# Keep radio buttons with their labels on line breaks

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an HTML form with sections laid out like this:
[image]

I do want the labels to be inline so that this section won't be 7 line breaks tall, but I would like to know how I can make sure the radio buttons stay with their labels.

Note: the labels are of varying lengths and are populated dynamically with data from the server, so I can't set a fixed width div without causing some weird spacing issues.

If there is an idiomatic way of doing this, please show me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put each input/label pair in a span, then set `white-space: nowrap` on the span.  Something like this:

```
<div class="radios">
    <span>
        <input type="radio" id="productTypeRC" />
        <label for="productTypeRC">RC</label>
    </span>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.radios > span
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Edit:**  The above technique suffers from a bug in Chrome where the pairs don't wrap and instead are hidden.  This bug is demonstrated in the question [Text doesn't wrap properly between elements having `white-space: nowrap`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21198456/361684). Solutions include using `float: left` with some margin added to make up for collapsed spacing, or to muck with the HTML until it works.  If you just put the `<input>` and `<label>` as the same line as the `<span>`, it works.

```
<div class="radios">
    <span><input type="radio" id="productTypeRC" /> <label for="productTypeRC">RC</label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" id="productTypeTC" /> <label for="productTypeTC">TC</label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" id="productTypeNS" /> <label for="productTypeNS">NS</label></span>
    ...
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/Z5uaT/57](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5uaT/57/)

Comment: nice they are in spans already. white-space: nowrap is new to me. i will try it now. thanks.

Comment: hmm. this only works somewhat. if there are too many button/label pairs those need to drop to the new line, but using white-space nowrap they do not. i want the whole pair to drop to a new line if necessary.

Comment: my bad. i had no spaces between the spans. this works great. thank you.

Comment: @Brandon - I'm surprised it behaves like that, but I see you are correct.  But we can still make it work.  See my updated answer with a link to a working demo.

Comment: you don't have to double wrap the spans. my html was generated by code so there were no spaces like this. <span>input label</span><span>input label</span>. changing it to <span>input label</span> <span>input label</span> totally worked.

Comment: @BrandonH - I finally figured out why it worked for you and not for me.  See my update.

Answer (score 5):

Put the checkbox inside the label (yes, this is valid) and make the label `inline-block` (see [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/Sz7fT/) for a demo). *IMO, this is a more elegant and semantic solution than the `span` wrapping [suggested by gilly3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714414/keep-radio-buttons-with-their-labels-on-line-breaks/6714422#6714422), which is why I decided to post even though you've already accepted an answer.*

Comment: he edited his answer after i figured out what was wrong. the double wrapping is not necessary.